# Windows DNS as secondary to BIND Master

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, bind

Could someone please explain to me the process of setting up DNS on Windows Server 2008 as a secondary to a BIND DNS Master.

The BIND master is setup and operating correctly as a Nameserver.

I'm trying to setup DNS in Windows Server 2008 to act as a secondary DNS nameserver, but when I attempt to transfer the zone data to the slave, Windows DNS gives me the following error:

"Zone Not Loaded by DNS Server - The DNS server encountered a problem while trying to load the zone. The transfer of zone data from the master server failed."

I think this might be because the BIND maser is not configured for zone transfers, however I read somewhere: "The default behaviour is to allow zone transfers to any host."

I am not too familiar with BIND, I've only used Windows DNS in the past.

Does anyone know where I might be going wrong, what I can do to fix this or explain to me how to setup the 2 servers correctly.

Comment: Question edited!

Comment: Did you check the global and the zone config for any 'allow-transfer'? By default BIND allows zone transfers to any host. But it's possible that the package has an altered config file and you will actually find this line somewhere 'allow-transfer {"none";};'.

Comment: I can't seem to find the named.conf file. It's not located at either: /var/named/named.conf or /etc/named.conf

Comment: The zone file does not contain that directive

Comment: Just found the file in /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf which includes 2 files: global.options.named.conf and kloxo.named.conf.

global.options.named.conf contained allow-transfer{"lxcenter";};

should this be set differently?

Comment: Probably. Try to add your windows server ip to the list. For example: allow-transfer { "lxcenter"; 10.10.10.10; } and make sure your firewall does not interfere.

Comment: All but my TXT records transferred

Comment: I added that as an answer and I would appreciate if you could flag it as such. I also advise to search serverfault for the TXT record problem, or add a new question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ip address, or the host name of your Windows DNS server to the allow-transfer list. For example: `allow-transfer { 10.10.10.10; }`.

Make sure your firewall does not interfere.